# Storing Python output in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I use `eval()` and I need to print the output. For example, `eval('1+1')` will return 2 but `eval('print('hello')')` will return `None`. How can I store the output of Python Shell?

Comment: Why are you using `eva()`l? You are getting `None` because `print()` has no return value thus it evaluates to `None`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler eval and external commands aren't related.

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you figure out a proper solution to the problem you're facing rather than using `eval()`, you won't have this new problem to solve. Can you tell us the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to create a telegram bot that acts like a python shell. I know that print() doesn't return anything so that is why I asked how can I store all python shell output as if I wrote print() in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to redirect standard output to a variable, use StringIO for a variable or use a file

```
from io import StringIO
# from StringIO import StringIO -- python 2.x
import sys
my_out = StringIO()
sys.stdout = my_out
print("hello") # now stored in my_out
```

or

```
my_file = open('my_file.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = my_file
print("hello") # now written to my_file.txt
```

Comment: This is correct but is missing a lot. The duplicate I linked has more thorough answers.

Comment: No module named 'StringIO'
Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to read sys.stdout? Because if so, my problem is solved.

Comment: @adamkatav sorry updated for 3.x